# Is there a way to get an iFrame from a postMessage?

Tags: javascript, postmessage

I've got a program that needs to juggle multiple iFrames at once that each communicate to the main window with postMessage.

I need to find a way to see what iFrame element sent a specific message.

I've tried using `message.source` however it only shows a Window element from inside the frame (that cannot be read as they're sandboxed). That excludes the possibility of finding it via the iFrame's contentWindow.

Comment: If they're sandboxed you won't be able to access it through `.contentWindow` either. The WindowProxy object that's passed in `message.source` is the same object. So you could retrieve your <iframe> by doing `[...document.querySelectorAll("iframe")].filter(el => el.contentWindow === evt.source)`, but that won't help you much I'm afraid.

Comment: The idea of PostMessage is to deliver _data_ between the windows, and then handle that data with the scripts of the windows.

Answer (score 0):

You can add any data to the sent message. So you could add an identifier inside each iframe and then in the parent you would know which iframe the message originated from.